# How can I share the common code between a web and PhoneGap application, both written with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have an Angular front-end that is being used as a website. However, I would also like to use it with PhoneGap to serve as a mobile application. The problem is that there are a few features in the mobile version that don't exist in the web version, such as a button to automatically insert the user's phone number into a text field.

More than 90% of both of these applications is the same, both in case of HTML/CSS and Javascript, and I have no idea how to keep this shared code in sync.

Is there a way to share the common code between these two applications (web and mobile) and yet allow them to change independently of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load CSS and JS (Not HTML) from server like we load from CDNs, but It will raise a Slow-StartUp issue in App.

also consider offline scenario. If User opens your app when he/she is offline your app won't work because it can't find the resource which should be loaded from server.

you can sync your HTML/CSS/JS with server using a plugin
have a look at https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/ maybe it could suffice your requirement.

Comment: My question isn't about how I can update the code on users' devices. Rather, it's about how I can share the common js/css/htmls between a PhoneGap and a web application.

Comment: you can load JS and css from server but it will raise slow-startup issue in mobile app.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Can you edit your answer to reflect my question so that I can accept?